# SwiftUI Map() zoom control

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is for Xcode 15 beta 3 and IOS17.

I have a Map() which I instantiate using

```
@State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .userLocation(followsHeading: true, fallback: .automatic)

Map(position: $position) {
   UserAnnotation()
}
```

I also have map annotations inside a ForEach struct.

I am looking for a way to adjust zoom level of this map according to the speed at which the user is moving, and haven't found a way to do it so far.

I've tried changing MapCameraBounds inside .onChange which observes CLLocation speed, but it's not really effective. Manually setting .camera means I can't follow user's heading.

I don't have a MRC as I just don't seem to have a way of making it work at all.  Looking for some input.

** EDIT

Is this a good way to adjust Zoom of a Map, while maintaining userLocation tracking with followsHeading = true.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var locationManager: LocationManager
    
    @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .userLocation(followsHeading: true, fallback: .automatic)
    @State private var bounds: MapCameraBounds? 

    @State private var zoom: Double = 1000
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            Map(position: $position, bounds: bounds) {
                UserAnnotation()
            }      
        }
        .onChange(of: locationManager.currentLocation) {
            let speed = locationManager.currentLocation.speed
            bounds = MapCameraBounds(minimumDistance: speed * 1000, maximumDistance: speed * 2000)
        }
    }

}
```

The zooming in/out is not smooth in all cases, with the screen jumping in/out so I think there should be a better way.

Comment: HI folks.  I'm still looking for your input into how to make this work. I've been at it for a couple weeks in between other things and can't seem to find a way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe there is more experience with MapKit for SwiftUI for IOS17 now, but I still can't make this work.  Anyone has a way to do this?